# Fire events at specific at specific progress as the seek bar progresses Android

Tags: android, audio, seekbar

I followed [this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-building-audio-player-tutorial/) to create an audio player.

Now **I want to add some events that fires events when the player reaches a specific progress.** 
For example, at 00:32 of the current audio, display a Toast.

The interface should look like this :

[image]

The white dots represents the events in this case.
Any idea?

Comment: What do you mean by lunch?

Comment: For example, at 00:32 of the current audio, display a Teast.

Comment: Have you read this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener.html?

Comment: Actually, i have a method updateProgressBar() that updates the current progress of the seekbar with the current running time of the audio. I can test if the current time corresponds to an event (i.e. if (CurrentTime= 00:32) Toas.Make... But I want also a graphical representation (White dots.. in the link above)

Comment: @SeifallahAzzabi : see [this](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/06/seek-to-specified-time-position-with.html) example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it guys, here is my code (that worked perfectly)

```
private ImageView CreateWhiteDot(int time) {
    ImageView WhiteDot = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
    float x = 0;
    float y = 0;
    WhiteDot.setImageResource(R.drawable.stop_dot_inactive);
    x = sbStopPlayerSlider.getX() + 15;
    x += ((sbStopPlayerSlider.getWidth() - 30) * time * 1000)
            / mpAudioPlayer.getDuration();
    WhiteDot.setX(x);
    y = sbStopPlayerSlider.getTranslationY()
            + sbStopPlayerSlider.getHeight() / 2;
    WhiteDot.setY(y);
    return WhiteDot;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the total duration of the supported audio file, using getDuration() method, use getCurrentPosition() method to find out if the seekbar has progressed your desired point. Fire events accordingly.

Comment: Yes this is what i said in my comment. But what for the white dots that i should place in on the seek bar? For example : audio duration = 01:00, the event should fire in 00:30 that means that the white dot should be placed in the middle of the progress bar. Like this http://d.pr/i/HSvs

Comment: These dots are predefined or would be dynamic?

Comment: Dynamic, loaded with the audio

Comment: I mean, points would be specific (points would depend on the duration of audio file?)

Comment: Every audio has a couple of points attached to it. When I load an audio I also load the points that goes with.

Comment: yeah sure, when i load the audio i load also the events and the exact time when they will fire.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21727/discussion-between-gaurav-and-seifallah-azzabi)